# wrong behavior of org-open-at-point with certain url

Tags: web-browser, url

NOTE, this only happens on mac. Linux is fine.

For the given link, which is directly copied from chrome url bar,

```
https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/#Quick Quiz 5
```

org-open-at-point will open it as https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/%23Quick%20Quiz%205

where as the correct url should be: https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/#Quick%20Quiz%205

note that in the wrong one, # becomes %23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, `org-open-at-point` invokes `open(1)` to visit the URL. It seems if the URL is invalid (e.g., contains spaces), `open(1)` will encode it before sending it to the web browser, for example, the command

```
~ $ open 'https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/#Quick Quiz 5'
```

opens https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/%23Quick%20Quiz%205 (404). However, if you the URL is valid, the `open(1)` works fine, the command

```
~ $ open 'https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/#Quick%20Quiz%205'
```

opens https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/#Quick%20Quiz%205 (200).

I think you can avoid the issue by entering URL in the valid encoded format. It's also possible to fix the encoding automatically via the following advice

```el
(define-advice browse-url-default-macosx-browser
    (:filter-args (args) fix-url)
  "Fix URL encoding."
  (cl-callf url-encode-url (car args))
  args)
```